# Default Inherited Widget in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, inherited-widget

I'm looking into `InheritedWidget` to learn and I want to know about the default `InheritedWidget`s provided by `Flutter`.

I've come to know that the `MediaQuery` class is by default `InheritedWidget` in `Flutter` and I'm guessing there are more of it.

If anyone knows about this then please do let me know.

Also will you please provide me the best example for `InheritedWidget`

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**InheritedWidget**  Class is the default inherited widget provided by flutter.
MediaQuery or other like widgets extend this widget to implement functioning.

Comment: Yes you are correct but i want to know about other widgets which are extending `InheritedWidget` by default in flutter.

Comment: BottomNavigationBarThemeButtonBarThemeCheckboxThemeCupertinoUserInterfaceLevelDataTableThemeDefaultAssetBundleDirectionalityDropdownButtonHideUnderlineFlexibleSpaceBarSettingsFocusTraversalOrderHeroControllerScopeInheritedModelInheritedNotifierInheritedThemeMediaQueryPrimaryScrollControllerRadioThemeScrollbarThemeScrollConfigurationSelectionRegistrarScopeSwitchThemeUnmanagedRestorationScope

Comment: will you please give me reference from where you get this

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html down a bit to "implementors".

Comment: You can also use your IDE to go to the "symbol" InheritedWidget, then "browse all references" to that class.